# Fixing SVG Fragment Sprite Slow Loading in Edge (Fine in Chrome, FF, Safari)

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

We have recently switched to SVG for our decorative images and logos.  We do this in the form of a single SVG file containing multiple SVG sections for each image.  We hide all SVG sections and only display the target SVG.

Here is a shortened example of our SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .img { display: none }
      .img:target { display: inline }
      .socialicon {fill:white}
      .btt {fill:#919191}
    </style>
  </defs>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <g id="icon-facebook" class="img socialicon">
      <path d="M9.5 3h2.5v-3h-2.5c-1.93 0-3.5 1.57-3.5 3.5v1.5h-2v3h2v8h3v-8h2.5l0.5-3h-3v-1.5c0-0.271 0.229-0.5 0.5-0.5z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <g id="icon-google-plus" class="img socialicon">
       <path d="M5.091 7.147v1.747h2.888c-0.116 0.75-0.872 2.197-2.888 2.197-1.737 0-3.156-1.441-3.156-3.216s1.419-3.216 3.156-3.216c0.991 0 1.65 0.422 2.028 0.784l1.381-1.331c-0.888-0.828-2.037-1.331-3.409-1.331-2.816 0.003-5.091 2.278-5.091 5.094s2.275 5.091 5.091 5.091c2.937 0 4.888-2.066 4.888-4.975 0-0.334-0.037-0.591-0.081-0.844h-4.806z"></path>
       <path d="M16 7h-1.5v-1.5h-1.5v1.5h-1.5v1.5h1.5v1.5h1.5v-1.5h1.5z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <g id="icon-twitter" class="img socialicon">
       <path d="M16 3.538c-0.588 0.263-1.222 0.438-1.884 0.516 0.678-0.406 1.197-1.050 1.444-1.816-0.634 0.375-1.338 0.65-2.084 0.797-0.6-0.638-1.453-1.034-2.397-1.034-1.813 0-3.281 1.469-3.281 3.281 0 0.256 0.028 0.506 0.084 0.747-2.728-0.138-5.147-1.444-6.766-3.431-0.281 0.484-0.444 1.050-0.444 1.65 0 1.138 0.578 2.144 1.459 2.731-0.538-0.016-1.044-0.166-1.488-0.409 0 0.013 0 0.028 0 0.041 0 1.591 1.131 2.919 2.634 3.219-0.275 0.075-0.566 0.116-0.866 0.116-0.212 0-0.416-0.022-0.619-0.059 0.419 1.303 1.631 2.253 3.066 2.281-1.125 0.881-2.538 1.406-4.078 1.406-0.266 0-0.525-0.016-0.784-0.047 1.456 0.934 3.181 1.475 5.034 1.475 6.037 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.341 0-0.144-0.003-0.284-0.009-0.425 0.641-0.459 1.197-1.038 1.637-1.697z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Here is an example of how we reference the SVG images:

```
<img 
  alt="Facebook" 
  id="facebookhome" 
  class="iconso" 
  src="/images/svg/svgsprite-1.6.svg#icon-facebook"
>
```

This works just great in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari.  Every new page load has an instant display of the images.

However, in IE11 and Edge, every time the page is loaded it's as if the SVG images are loaded last and it leaves the placeholder empty until everything else is loaded first (it seems).  It's only a very short delay (0.5-1s) however not very nice for UX and slightly offputting.

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Any suggestions, tips, and advice are greatly appreciated.

We are also running HTTP2 so maybe SVG sprites won't perform any better anyway?

Comment: This may sound weird, but I seem to recall some issue IE has with no size specced on the svg. You may try adding it to the svg tags, like so: `<svg  style="width:16px; height:16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16">`. Granted, that may not help at all.

Comment: Some users had already provided a feedback for this issue on Microsoft site. MS Edge Team had replied that issue will be fixed in new update. So You can check for latest update for Edge. If no any new update available then you can wait for the next update. You can also provide your feedback in link below. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17612393/